# Parsing multiple enum values (Flagged): Reading in a filter type from a query string

Tags: c#, filter, enums, enum-flags

I'm plan to make a page that displays info about user's in the form of a table. Each column will be a property of the table. I want someone viewing the table to be able to choose ways to filter the users. There will be two check boxes: 1 for reported users and 1 for creation date. I'm planning to make an enum called UserFilter like so:

```
public enum UserFilter
{
   None = 0,
   Date = 1,
   Reported = 2
}
```

If I need to add another type it's value will be set to 4 so that I can tell which enums are selected through a bitwise or (3 would be both 1 and 2). The problem I'm having is with reading in an enum from the query string. I guess I could do something like posting back with an int (0 for none, 1 for date, 2 for report, 3 for both) but I would like to try posting back with the actual string. I'm not sure how I would parse "Date|Reported" into an enum value that doesn't exist in UserFilter.

In a nutshell: Is there a clean way to parse "Date|Reported" into the value 3 without adding another value to my enum?

Comment: just pass the Data as an int, that is the whole point of an Enum, you pass data back and forth as an int, but the business logic converts the int to a string value ( through the Enum)  otherwise you might as well just have a data type of string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try something like

```
string enumString = "Date|Reported";
UserFilter uf = enumString.Split('|').ToList().Select(e =>
{
    UserFilter u;
    Enum.TryParse(e, true, out u);
    return u;
}).Aggregate((u, c) => u = u | c);
```

I would however recomend that you change your enum to

```
public enum UserFilter
{
    None = 1,
    Date = 2,
    Reported = 4
}
```

as if you have it your way `None|Date` is the same as `Date`, because `0 + 1 => 1`

**EDIT**

As @ScottSelby stated, this would also work

```
UserFilter u = (UserFilter) 3;
//or 6 rather than 3 if you take my comment above into consideration
```

Comment: I think "None" might be a bad name. By that I meant that neither Date nor Reported were selected. I wouldn't have a checkbox for None which is why I had it set as 0. If a user manually puts in ?filter=None|None|None|Date|None&... I would want to try to give them a list filtered by date. I like your solution for parsing the filter parameter and am going to try that out. Thanks!